# What is inline data in a class?

Tags: c++, inline, class-design

In his talk about [Designing value classes for modern C++](https://meetingcpp.com/tl_files/2014/talks/Marc-Mutz-C++11-Value-Classes-public.pdf), Marc Mutz mentions the concept of *inline data* (in the 6th slide, when talking about thin abstractions).

I searched for what that means, but couldn't find anything close to a definition of what inline data is (even in the standard, in which I did not find any mention of "inline data").

I suspect the concept may be akin to inline functions, i.e. when assigning to/reading from it, the compiler optimizes away the overhead that comes with the fact that it's a member of a class, though I'm not sure.

So what it is exactly, and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing novel I'm afraid. He just means class data that's defined in the class definition, the bog-standard way, rather than being hidden off in a pimpl. The talk [is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cwVvBsZE6M)
and he explains this about 9:30 in.

Comment: Oh, indeed, it was that simple. Thanks!